# Why is the number of excited vibrational modes $g(\nu)d\nu$ proportional to $x^2e^{-x}$ in Debye's theory?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, thermodynamics, statistical-mechanics, harmonic-oscillator

I come across a problem in Terrell Hill's "Introduction to statistical thermodynamics" saying that:

> In the Debye theory, the number of excited vibrational modes in the frequency range $\nu$ to $\nu+d\nu$, at temperature $T$, is proportional to $x^2e^{-x}$, where $x=h\nu/kT$. The maximum in this function occurs at a frequency $\nu′=2kT/h$; hence $\nu′\rightarrow0$ as $T\rightarrow0$.

When I attempt to solve the problem, the first thing came into my mind was that $g(\nu)\sim \alpha \nu^2$. Since the problem says that $g(\nu)d\nu\sim x^2e^{-x}$. I guess it has something to do with the partition function of single excited classic oscillator ($n>0$):

$$q(\theta_i)=\frac{e^{-\frac{3\theta_i}{2T}}}{1-e^{-\theta_i/T}}.$$

where $\theta_i=h\nu_i/k$. So the canonical partition function $Q$ for a monoatomic crystal in Debye's theory becomes:

$$-\ln Q = \frac{N\phi(0)}{2kT}+\int^\infty_0\left[\ln(1-e^{h\nu/kT})+\frac{3h\nu}{2kT}\right]g(\nu)d\nu.$$

And I also know that $\int^\infty_0g(\nu)d\nu=3N$. But how should I proceed to get $g(\nu)d\nu\sim x^2e^{-x}$ from here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'll just give some general comments here.

Firstly, as you say, the density of states is $g(\nu)\propto \nu^2$ for $\nu\leq\nu_D$, the Debye cutoff. This doesn't change during the derivation of the Debye result, so you should not be trying to show $g(\nu)\sim x^2e^{-x}$ (last sentence of OP).

The quantity referred to in the question is the density of occupied, or excited, states. This is not $g(\nu)$, but $g(\nu)$ multiplied by a temperature-dependent occupation number $\langle n\rangle$. Clearly, the expression $x^2e^{-x}$ corresponds to $g(\nu)\exp(-h\nu/kT)$, once you've made the variable substitutions.

The quantum mechanical Bose-Einstein formula for the average occupation number of phonon states at temperature $T$ is (as I'm sure you know)
$$
\langle n\rangle = \frac{1}{\exp(h\nu/kT)-1}
$$
Why is Hill using the classical Boltzmann factor $\exp(-h\nu/kT)$ instead of this? It seems that he wants to discuss the peak in the function
$g(\nu)\langle n\rangle$ *at low temperature*, where the Boltzmann formula is a reasonable approximation to $\langle n\rangle$. It gives you an expression that is easier to differentiate.

However, you would use the proper Bose-Einstein formula to derive the results of Debye theory.